# Content script for pausing youtube videos

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am currently working on a google chrome extension that features a content script for altering youtube pages. I have done some work with altering the DOM already and all of that works, however, I have been looking for solutions to have the youtube video pause when the page loads.

I initially thought perhaps I could simulate a keystroke as the spacebar pauses youtube videos. I also tried using javascript to pause the video but I don't think it works with Youtube's custom video player.

Don't feel obligated to write any code for this but if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you show us something you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the main page of a video, the HTML5 video element playing the video has a specific class, so you can target that; and as an HTML5 video element, it has the play() and pause() methods already.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.html5-main-video').forEach(vid => vid.pause());
```

That will pause all HTML5 main videos on the page. Helpfully enough, that's the same class used by the little autoplaying video on some channel pages, so it should work for those as well :)

(Don't worry about Flash videos; YouTube hasn't supported those for years now.)

Comment: Thank you so much you just saved my life.